# Every object's attribute update when I just want one

Tags: python, numpy

When making objects of a certain class, I give them a matrix as an attribute and store these objects in a different class, however when I change this matrix for one object, it changes for every object

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = []
        matrix = np.matrix([
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0]
        ])
        for i in range(10):
            newObject = A(matrix)
            self.objects.append(newObject)

objectB = B()
objectB.objects[0].matrix[0] = [1,1,1] # change top row of first object to 1,1,1
for object in objectB.objects:
    print(object.matrix)
```

The code above prints 10 matrices all with [1,1,1] as the top row but should just print the first matrix with [1,1,1] on the top row and the other 9 matrices with all zeros

Comment: Sounds like some code (possibly within `__init__`) is creating aliases rather than copies. How is `__orientation` initialized? For more specific help, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman , I am not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible problem of a suitable length.
I have edited the question to give the `__init__` functions of the classes. Sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure this help, but there's a Rubik's cube example on ursina's GitHub, in samples/rubiks_cube.py that doesn't use a matrix.

Comment: ALL of your pieces have the exact same `orientation` matrix.  I don''t mean they have the same value, I mean you are making 9 references to a single matrix.  Now, it looks like you are setting `self.orientation` and using `self.__orientation`, so I can't guess how those are related.

Comment: @TimRoberts When I first create the cube, I want all the pieces to have the same `orientation` matrix as (at least the way I have modeled the cube), they all face the same way. As for the setting of `self.orientation` and `self.__orientation`. I just tried removing the `__` to see if this would work, I have edited back to what it should be.

Problem arises when I make a turn and I think I update the `__orientation` of one layer, the `__orientation` of every piece in the entire cube also changes.

Comment: Maybe try `self.__orientation = orientation.copy()` instead of just `self.__orientation = orientation`

Comment: When you read `self.__orientation[0,i]`, no matter which piece you are using, you are referring to the ONE SINGLE matrix that you created at init time.  They're all changing because they're all referring to the exact same matrix.  There is only ONE orientation matrix in your entire program, with 9 pointers to it.  There are not 9 matrices.

Comment: @JohnColeman This has fixed the issue, I'm not sure how to mark this as solved

Comment: @TimRoberts I see what you mean now, Issue is fixed this was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the copy function when creating the matrix attribute in class A

```
self.matrix = matrix.copy()
```

This makes a unique matrix for each object instead of referencing the same matrix.

Comment: Adding some explanation of why this solved your issue would be helpful to future readers. Also, you can accept your answer to mark the issue as resolved.